How to fill PowerShell input with a Python Script?
I've installed PowerShell on a Linux device and I need to access the module ExchangeOnlineManagement.
I would like to use a python script to manage any actions automatically on the Powershell Exchange.
However, I'm able to connect on PowerShell Exchange but I didn't find a way to fill the input requested by PowerShell Exchange Module.
There is my code:
import subprocess
import sys
def run(cmd):
    completed = subprocess.run(["/xxxx/xxxx/xxxx/xxxx/pwsh", "-Command", cmd], stdout=True, stderr=True)

    return completed

if __name__ == '__main__':
    connect_command = "Connect-ExchangeOnline -CertificateFilePath '/XXX/XXX/XXX/certificate.pfx' -CertificatePassword (Get-Credential).password -AppID 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' -Organization 'myorg.onmicrosoft.com'"
    connect_info = run(connect_command)
    if connect_info.returncode != 0:
        print("An error occured: %s", connect_info.stderr)
    else:
        print("Connected")

At this moment, PowerShell prompt me this:

I've tried to fill it with "sys.stdout.write('myuser')" but my script is waiting for my output and doesn't read the instruction.
Does anyone have any idea how to manage this?

Have you tried using the -Credential or -InlineCredential parameter of Connect-ExchangeOnline?

This is a need to connect with a certificate, I'm authenticating with an App which is in the registered in Entra ID. I cannot use a user/password as authentication method

There is a -CertificatePassword parameter.

That is what I'm using, but it prompts me a user/password to fill and I would like this be filled from my script

The argument -Confirm:$false helped me for executing the command and ignoring the prompt.
Like this:
Disconnect-ExchangeOnline -Confirm:$false


One way to dodge the situation was to do this:
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString 'MyPassword' -AsPlainText -Force; Connect-ExchangeOnline -CertificateFilePath '/XXX/XXX/XXX/certificate.pfx' -CertificatePassword $password -AppID 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' -Organization 'myorg.onmicrosoft.com'

The semicolon allows me to make two commands in one. I could put my password in a variable et pass it in my args.
I guess this is obvious for people who know PowerShell.
